# JS function not displaying anything

Tags: javascript

I have made a function and captured the value of a textbox. On a button click, it should alert the value.
The code is:

```
function substitute (argument) {
    var myVal=document.getElementById('myTextBox').value();
    alert(myVal);
    if (myVal.length==0) {
        alert('Empty Textbox');
    };
}
```

It is then executed using this:

```
<input type="button" name="Button" value="Click Me" onclick="substitute();">
```

But nothing happens. Please tell me where am I doing it wrong.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Wild guess: Your text box doesn't have an ID.

Comment: The "value" property will never have a function as its value. You're trying to call it like a function however (that's what `()` does).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes i have given textbox the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` is not a function, it's a property, therefore:

```
var myVal=document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;
```

As you're brand new to JS, I'll give you a piece of advice: If you want to manipulate the DOM, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: but i wanna learn Angular and all, so ive started using javascript.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is just a JS library that makes it much easier (and faster) to do some things: it's still JavaScript.

Comment: +1 for having the right answer. -1 for suggesting jQuery for such a trivial operation.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Good. Angular uses jQuery as well (or a subset of jQuery if the whole lib isn't available)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I doubt this *trivial operation* is only piece of JS code he'll write on his website. Better use jQuery from the start, it can only save time (also, see the comment about angular).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Better still, write your own toolkit. Now *that* saves time. Plus you learn stuff.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Writing your own toolkit saves time? Am I detecting sarcasm correctly?

Comment: @kraxor Not at all. There is no sarcasm in what I said. Whenever I create a project, I write my own functions for everything I need, and nothing I don't. If I need something new, I write a function for it. In this way, I save time which would otherwise be spent downloading large amount of unused JavaScript, or processing large numbers of superfluous instructions to figure out just what the hell `$("#"+$(this).attr("id")).attr("id","derp")` means. That last bit was probably uncalled for, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few errors:

1. `.value()` is not a function: use `.value`
2. You  don't need that semicolon at the end of the `if` statement
3. Your text box might not have the `id` that you're referring to: make sure that you have `id="myTextBox"` in the opening tag
4. While it won't cause any errors, your function definition lists a parameter, but you do not pass one when you call it.

Always check your browser console for errors if nothing is happening. Always.

```
function substitute () { // Parameter "argument" is not necessary
    var myVal=document.getElementById('myTextBox').value; //.value, not .value()
    alert(myVal);
    if (myVal.length==0) {
        alert('Empty Textbox');
    }; // You don't need this semicolon
} // You were missing this curly brace
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/47zYY/)

Comment: you mean semicolon is never necessary in if else statements?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini No: the brackets denote the beginning and end of the statement. You need semicolons on the *inside* just like you would anywhere else, but you never need a semicolon after the closing curly brace.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini If you do have the proper `id` for your textbox, then I'm fairly certain that all you need is to remove the parentheses from `value` and add one more closing curly brace at the end.

Comment: @AstroCB he wasn't missing the `}`, he was just lazy with the formatting.

Comment: @AstroCB I just have.

Answer (score 1):

In Your code, you are not passing any parameter to function subsititute(), But @ function definition you wrote substitute(argument). Thats a big issue, and also you put there is a semi-column after if condition inside the function. No need of it

Try This..

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Hello" />
<input type="button" name="Button" value="Click Me" onclick="substitute();" />
```

In script part,

```
function subsitute()
{
  var myVal=$('#myText').val();
  alert(myVal);
  if (myVal=='')
  {
    alert('Empty Textbox');
  }
}
```

Comment: While technically correct, the fact that a parameter is not passed does not matter: it doesn't stop it from [functioning properly](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/47zYY/). It's not a "big issue."

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/tewudopi/1/edit

Add an ID to the button. When referencing the button, it is not ".value()", it is simply ".value".

As a side note, you should use === instead of == to compare.

```
function substitute() {
  var myVal=document.getElementById('myTextBox');
  alert(myVal.value);
  if (myVal.value.length===0) {
    alert('Empty Textbox');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function substitute() {

var myVal=document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;
if (myVal.length>0) {
alert(myVal);
}
if (myVal.length==0) {
    alert('Empty Textbox');
}
}
</script>
<input type="button" name="Button" value="Click Me" onclick="substitute();">
<textarea name="myTextBox" id="myTextBox"></textarea>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dev310103/F333L/)